# Global variable being reset after each call

Tags: c, global-variables

In my project I'm using a global variable but it's not working as expected because it is initialized everytime it's executed and honestly I don't know what could be going on.

**The variable is cookingSignalReceived.**

The program is structured as follows:

```
//File Controller.c: 

while (1)
{
    Controller_Run_State_Machine();
}


void Controller_Run_State_Machine(void)
{
   /* start of activity code */
   Inputs_ReadSensors();
   Comms_CheckReceivedData();
   Controller_UpdateSTM();
}
```

The problem is inside Comms file:

```
//File Comms.c

uint8_t cookingSignalReceived = 0;

void Comms_CheckReceivedData(void)
{
   /* start of activity code */
   uint8_t uartDataAvailable = Comms_R_UART0_checkIfDataAvailable();

   if (uartDataAvailable == 1)
   {
      Comms_ParseReceivedCommand();
   }
}

void Comms_ParseReceivedCommand(void)
{
    /* start of activity code */
    /* UserCode{499E2AA6-1F61-4753-9221-77F85E7B5D92}:YjMeKqu95e */
    uint8_t CRC_check_OK = 0;
    uint8_t* buffer;
    /* UserCode{499E2AA6-1F61-4753-9221-77F85E7B5D92} */

    Comms_R_UART0_resetFlag_dataAvailable();
    buffer = Comms_R_UART0_getBuffer();
    CRC_check_OK = Comms_crcCheck(buffer);

    if (CRC_check_OK == 1)
    {
        Comms_processMessage(buffer); //<-- Variable is used in this function
    }
}
```

Global variable is used inside Comms_processMessage(). The issue is that every time that the function is called, the global variable is set to the initial value. Do you find anything strange here?

EDITED:

```
void Comms_processMessage(uint8_t* buffer)
{
    /* UserCode{BCB3B791-2DF9-492b-B53B-6FEB24BD8F77}:eyCoSfmCKb */

    uint8_t message = buffer[0];
    uint8_t param1 = buffer[1];
    uint8_t param2 = buffer[2];


    //---------------------------------------------------------------------
    //                     START COOKING 1ST STEP REQUEST
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------
    if (message == MSG_COOK_1ST && param1 == START_PARAM)
    {
        // Wait for second frame
        cookingSignalReceived = 1;
        #ifdef DEBUG
                R_UART0_Send("Cook 1st step!!", sizeof(char) * 15);
        #endif
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------
    //                     START COOKING 2ND STEP REQUEST
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------
    else if (message == MSG_COOK_2ND && param1 == START_PARAM)
    {
        // Wait for second frame
        if (cookingSignalReceived == 1)
        {
            Controller_signalsBufferEnqueue(cookingSignal);
        }
        #ifdef DEBUG
                R_UART0_Send("Cook 2nd step!!", sizeof(char) * 15);
        #endif
    }

}
```

Note that my original idea was to use a local static variable but I was having the same issue so I tried with a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

In certain cases the MCUs restart because unrecoverable errors or bad hardware settings. This should be the problem! A cause of this MCUs behaviour may be also bad pointers management.